# c# getting item in row from datatable

Tags: c#

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string[] temprow={"","","",row[3].ToString()};
        dtworklist.Rows.Add(temprow);
    }
```

dt is my datatable. i need to get the 3rd element in the row and put it into an array. the above is what i tried so far with no luck. how do i do it?

Comment: what do you mean by "with no luck"?  What happened?

Comment: What do you do with the array after? From what i can tell Dtworklist is a data table also, you would need to create a row from the data table to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    int i=0;
    List<string> l=new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        l.Add(Convert.ToString(row[2]));
    }
    string[] stringArray=l.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you try:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    DataRow added = dtworklist.NewRow();
    int columnOfInterest = 2; // could be the column name as a string too
    added[columnOfInterest] = row[columnOfInterest];
}
```

Note that I have used index of 2 because the first index in the list is zero. If you want the third item you would be interested in index 2.